# Format JavaScript Date as Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I cannot get the second time to format properly:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var local = new Date();
  var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + local.getMinutes() + ":" + local.getSeconds();

  var remote = new Date();
  var remotedatetime = remote.getHours() + ":" + remote.getMinutes() + ":" + remote.getSeconds();

  var remoteoffset = remote.setHours(local.getHours() - 5);

  $('#local-time').html(localdatetime);
  $('#remote-time').html(remoteoffset);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

My Time:
<div id="local-time"></div>
Their time:
<div id="remote-time"></div>
```

`local-time` is perfect and displays "hh:mm:ss"

`remote-time` just displays a list of random numbers.

How can I make `remote-time` "hh:mm:ss", too?

Comment: remoteoffset.toString() ?

Comment: You'll never deal with all the possible timezones like this, use UTC

Comment: _"remote-time just displays a list of random numbers."_ - They're not random, they're just not the format you were expecting. Notice you never use the `remotedatetime` variable after you set it to the formatted value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adjusting `remote` *after* getting its string representation, so that's doing you no good.

Then you're displaying the result of `setHours()` (milliseconds since January 1, 1970) rather than the string.

This is what I *think* you're aiming for:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var local = new Date();
  var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + pad(local.getMinutes()) + ":" + pad(local.getSeconds());

  var remote = new Date();
  remote.setHours(local.getHours() - 5);
  var remotedatetime = remote.getHours() + ":" + pad(remote.getMinutes()) + ":" + pad(remote.getSeconds());

  $('#local-time').html(localdatetime);
  $('#remote-time').html(remotedatetime);
}, 1000);

function pad(t) {
  var st = "" + t;
  
  while (st.length < 2)
    st = "0" + st;
    
  return st;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

My Time:
<div id="local-time"></div>
Their time:
<div id="remote-time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var local = new Date();
    var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + local.getMinutes() + ":" + local.getSeconds();

    var remote = new Date();
    remote.setHours(local.getHours() - 5);
    var remotedatetime = remote.getHours() + ":" + remote.getMinutes() + ":" + remote.getSeconds();

    $('#local-time').html(localdatetime);
    $('#remote-time').html(remotedatetime);
},1000);
```